# Make BlurView effect in TabBarController

Tags: ios

I have a ViewController inside a TabBarController, I want to add a BlurView in that ViewController, which also affects TabBarController, how to do that.

If I use this code:

```
func presentBlurView() {
        blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: blurEffectStyle)
        blurView1 = UIView()
        blurView1!.frame = self.view.frame
        blurView1!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
        self.view.addSubview(blurView1!)

        blurView1!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
            blurView1!.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 0),
            blurView1!.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            blurView1!.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.rightAnchor,constant:0),
            blurView1!.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.bottomAnchor,constant:0)
            ])
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissProjectDetailViewRightSight:")
        tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        blurView1!.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }
```

It just shows inside the whole view of ViewController, not effect to TabBarController. But if I change like this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.addSubview(blurView1!)
```

It works with TabBarController, but in this case, very hard to handle somethings. Are there anyways to solve this problem. Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried working through the superviews of your `viewController` to find the Tab Controller?

Comment: So self.view.addSubview(blurView1!) should be view.superview?.addSubview(blurView1!), right?

Comment: Try logging the class of each successive superview to see what you have available.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
self.tabBarController?.view.addSubview(blurView1!)
```

Comment: It crash, po self.tabBarController -> nil. Maybe this ViewController is not embedded in TabBarController.

Comment: @khuong291 you're right, if  `self.tabBarController` is nil, that means that your view controller in not embedded in UITabBarController.